# Render v-html with v-for in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vuejs 2 and I´d like to render a v-html with v-for like below.

I have tried the next but no look. Is it possible?

```
<template>
    <div v-html="mycontent"></div>
</template>
...
export default {
...
data:()=>({
mycontent: '',
datateste: ['aa', 'bb'],
})

mounted(){
  this.mycontent =
      "<template v-for='item in datateste'><p>{{ item }}</p></template>"
  } 
}
```

Comment: can i ask why you dont put it directly into `template`

Comment: Hi, because It comes from backend

Comment: You should take a look in vue dynamic components

Comment: Which part comes from the backend? Do you mean it is a server-side rendering or an API?